# Is there a way to check how many jobs a user has in the queue?

Tags: linux, queue, portable-batch-system

I know commands, like qsub, qstat -a, qstat -an, etc.

But how can I find how many jobs a single user has in the queue (not all necessarily running) at any given time?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you're looking for the 'user' option of `qstat`. `qstat -u username` lists all jobs belonging to the given user.
Wildcards can be included with a backslash: `qstat -u \\*` lists all jobs.

To answer your specific question (total jobs), you can use `wc` to count the lines that `qstat` outputs:

```
qstat -u username | wc -l
```

But that will give two more than the actual jobs because `qstat` has two header lines. So the full command you may want is:

```
expr $(qstat -u username | wc -l) - 2
```

Which asks for the jobs by user username, counts the numbers of lines, and subtracts 2.

Answer (score 3):

Number of header lines may be different from 2 (e.g., on our Cray it is 5).
Another solution is:

```
qselect -u username | wc -l
```

`qselect` does not produce header lines.

Answer (score 1):

An actual solution is
`qstat -u username |grep username |wc -l`
this way the number of header lines does not matter.

Comment: Since the answer is already accepted. you may take this solution and put it as a comment inside the accepted answer port to compliment it.